# What is this symbol in visual studio 2013? [image inside]

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

What is this symbol? What does it represent?

It has appeared in the bar that is used for break points. I can't seam to find any information about it (and am probably not describing it correctly in the search terms).

[image: unknown symbol]

Comment: can't you read the tooltip? It says "Toogle a Bookmark on the current line". Which seems pretty self-explanatory. If you want to read more look at the official docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wffxsy0.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and no when I hover over it nothing comes up.

Comment: @PeterT: That tooltip's only on the toggle button itself, not on the symbol in the margin. And clicking in the margin only toggles breakpoints. Bookmarks are great, but they're not easy to discover.

Comment: In "classic" keyboard layout bookmarks are toggled by `Ctrl+F2` combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of answering the question, as mentioned in the comments, the symbol is a bookmark symbol for that line of code.

Bookmarks are there so that you can fly around your project to the parts that you have to go to regularly so that you can improve your workflow and program faster.